# Find hotels which has specific array as an attribute using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

There are so many hotels and each hotel has an attribute of **meal** which is of array type. So i want to know which mongoose function can help me to find those hotels whose meal attribute is equals to given array?``

Answer (score 1):

```
Hotel.find({ meal: { $eq: givenArray } }, ...
```

Keep in mind that the order affects the `$eq` comparison